# Find the value of $x$ when the powers are logarithmic functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Find the value of $x$ such that
>
> $( \frac {x}{2} )^{\log_n 4} -(\frac {3}{x})^{\log_n 9} =0$

**What I tried,**

$( \frac {x}{2} )^{\log_n 4} =(\frac {3}{x})^{\log_n 9}$

Cross multiply,

$x^{\log_n 36}= (3^{\log_n 9})(2^{\log_n 4}
)$

Then I noticed if I changed to base $3$ for $\log_n 9$,it would give me $\frac {2}{\log_3 n}$ or $2 \log_n 3$

Then if I changed to base $2$ for $\log_n 4$,it would give me $\frac {2}{\log_2 n}$ or $2 \log_n 2$

With different powers of both $2$ and $3$, I can't really join them up together.

Comment: Take your last equation, raise it to the power of $1/\log(36)$.

Comment: raise it to the power of $\frac {1}{log_{36} n} $ ?

Comment: No, $1/\log_n(36)$

Comment: I'm sorry ,but I'm extremely lost and how to raise it to that? Sorry...

Comment: It's like how if you have $x^3=y$ and you want to solve for $x$, you can raise both sides to the power of $1/3$ to get $x = y^{1/3}$.

Comment: Ohhhhh,okay I will try first then!

Comment: what is $n$ here?

Answer (score 1):

Making it like $$\left( \frac {x}{2} \right)^{\alpha} -\left( \frac {3}{x}\right)^{\beta} =0$$ using your way $$\left( \frac {x}{2} \right)^{\alpha} =\left( \frac {3}{x}\right)^{\beta}\implies \frac {x^\alpha}{2^\alpha}=\frac {3^\beta}{x^\beta}$$ As you did, cross-multiply $$x^\alpha\cdot x^\beta= 2^\alpha\cdot3^\beta\implies x^{\alpha+\beta}=2^\alpha\cdot3^\beta$$ Take logarithms $$(\alpha+\beta)\log(x)=\alpha\log(2)+\beta\log(3)\implies \log(x)=\frac{\alpha\log(2)+\beta\log(3) }{\alpha+\beta }$$ and then use $x=e^{\log(x)}$.

Answer (score 0):

take the logarithm of both sides we obtain
$$\log_n(4)\ln(x/2)=\log_n (9)\ln(3/x)$$
using the power rule
$$2\log_n(2)\ln(x/2)=2\log_n(3)\ln(3/x)$$
$$\ln(2)(\ln(x)-\ln(2))=\ln(3)(\ln(3)-\ln(x))$$ if $$\ln(n)\ne 0$$
$$\ln(2)\ln(x)-\ln(2)^2=\ln(3)^2-\ln(x)\ln(3)$$
isolating $\ln(x)$
$$\ln(x)=\frac{\ln(3)^2+\ln(2)^2}{\ln(2)+\ln(3)}$$
from here you can find $$x$$

Comment: So,if we have equations with logarithmic powers,we use logarithms to bring the power down?